# Simple accordion js

Tags: javascript

I am having issue removing previous active class, I want to open an item with accordion, but whenever I open next item I wan't the previous one to close. How can I achieve this?

```js
let accordion = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion-item")
let accordionText = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion-text")
accordion.forEach((item, i) => {
 
    accordion[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
  accordionText[i].classList.toggle("active")

  })

})
```

```css
.accordion-text {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion-item">
  <div class="accordion-label">
  Test
  </div>
 <div class="accordion-text">
  <p>
  orem ipsum – tekst składający się z łacińskich i quasi-łacińskich wyrazów, mający korzenie w klasycznej łacinie, wzorowany n
  </p>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="accordion-item">
  <div class="accordion-label">
  Test
  </div>
 <div class="accordion-text">
  <p>
  orem ipsum – tekst składający się z łacińskich i quasi-łacińskich wyrazów, mający korzenie w klasycznej łacinie, wzorowany n
  </p>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="accordion-item">
  <div class="accordion-label">
  Test
  </div>
 <div class="accordion-text">
  <p>
  orem ipsum – tekst składający się z łacińskich i quasi-łacińskich wyrazów, mający korzenie w klasycznej łacinie, wzorowany n
  </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

I tried something like this but doesn't seem to work. I am getting this error
`"<a class='gotoLine' href='#83:31'>83:31</a> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined"`

```js
accordion.forEach((item, i) => {
  let previousItem = null;
  accordionText[previousItem].classList.remove("active")
    accordion[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
  accordionText[i].classList.toggle("active")
    previousItem = i
  })

})
```

Comment: `let previousItem = null`: Here's your problem. You're basically saying `accordionText[null]` which is `undefined`. Moreover, your `previousItem` variable is local, so saving `i` in it doesn't accomplish what you're aiming at, as it's redefined in every loop. Also, your approach doesn't account for the case where the next item is open.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to delete the `active` class each time we click the label element.

```js
const accordionText = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion-text');
const labels = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion-label');

labels.forEach((label, i) => {
  label.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
e.target.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('active');
labels.forEach((label, j) => {
  if (j !== i) {
    label.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('active');
  }
});
  });
});
```

```css
.accordion-text {
  display: none;
}

.accordion-label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion-item">
  <div class="accordion-label">
    Test
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-text">
    <p>
      orem ipsum – tekst składający się z łacińskich i quasi-łacińskich wyrazów, mający korzenie w klasycznej łacinie, wzorowany n
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="accordion-item">
  <div class="accordion-label">
    Test
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-text">
    <p>
      orem ipsum – tekst składający się z łacińskich i quasi-łacińskich wyrazów, mający korzenie w klasycznej łacinie, wzorowany n
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="accordion-item">
  <div class="accordion-label">
    Test
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-text">
    <p>
      orem ipsum – tekst składający się z łacińskich i quasi-łacińskich wyrazów, mający korzenie w klasycznej łacinie, wzorowany n
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Consider adding an explanation of what you've altered. The OP is clearly new to JavaScript.

Comment: It should work same way as in my original post, when I click again on same item it should close, here it doesnt

Comment: @c398wwsfa I did the update now it works as it should.

Answer (score -1):

In order to achieve the desired behavior, you need to remove the active class if it's present on any element unless that is the current element.

```js
let accordion = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion-item");
let accordionText = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion-text");

accordion.forEach((item, i) => {
 accordion[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
   accordionText.forEach((el) => {
     if (el.classList.contains('active') && el !== accordionText[i]) {
       el.classList.remove('active');
     }
   });

   accordionText[i].classList.toggle("active");
 });
});
```

```css
.accordion-text {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion-item">
  <div class="accordion-label">
  Test
  </div>
 <div class="accordion-text">
  <p>
  orem ipsum – tekst składający się z łacińskich i quasi-łacińskich wyrazów, mający korzenie w klasycznej łacinie, wzorowany n
  </p>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="accordion-item">
  <div class="accordion-label">
  Test
  </div>
 <div class="accordion-text">
  <p>
  orem ipsum – tekst składający się z łacińskich i quasi-łacińskich wyrazów, mający korzenie w klasycznej łacinie, wzorowany n
  </p>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="accordion-item">
  <div class="accordion-label">
  Test
  </div>
 <div class="accordion-text">
  <p>
  orem ipsum – tekst składający się z łacińskich i quasi-łacińskich wyrazów, mający korzenie w klasycznej łacinie, wzorowany n
  </p>
  </div>

</div>
```